# I keep getting this error when I enter this option

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I can't get this problem and I believe the syntax is correct but I keep getting this error when I enter list option.

> script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'input' before initialization
> at script.js:5:5

```js
let input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!")
const todos = []
while (input.toLowerCase() !== "quit" && input.toLowerCase() !== "q") {

    if (input === 'list') {
        console.log('++++++++++')
    }

    let input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!");
}
console.log("OK!! Quit the app")
```

Comment: You are trying to redefine `input` , `let input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!")`
Wouldn't  `input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!"` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `let` on the 2nd `input` (in `while`)

`let input` means you want to declare `input` again, but you already declare it in the global scope

```js
let input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!")
const todos = []
while (input.toLowerCase() !== "quit" && input.toLowerCase() !== "q") {

    if (input === 'list') {
        console.log('++++++++++')
    }

    input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!");
}
console.log("OK!! Quit the app")
```

Just an additional note to my answer that `let` is also scoped.

Scoping variables means the first `input` and second `input` declarations are not relative (because of your redundant `let` in the second `input`), and then it checks that you use `prompt` for the second `input` declaration (in the same scope of `while`), but it goes before `let input` (the second one), so that's why that error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You are redefining the input in line 8 or something. Look at the pic, it didn't throw an error for me when I removed `let`.

I removed the `prompt` commands not to run into another error since I need to import a package like readline-sync.

```
let input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!")
const todos = []
while (input.toLowerCase() !== "quit" && input.toLowerCase() !== "q") {

    if (input === 'list') {
        console.log('++++++++++')
    }

    input = prompt("What would you like to do ?!!!!!");
}
console.log("OK!! Quit the app")
```

^^ this should work

Answer (score 0):

Look. You define `input` in the uppermost block. Then you define the same `input` in `while` block. So, inside `while` js will use your second definition. And yes, at `if(input === ...)` you try to access input before initialization. Try to read this [MDN:let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)